# Копирование в буфер обмена текста из диалога PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qclipboard, qinputdialog

Как можно реализовать копирование введенного текста 
в диалоге `QInputDialog.getText()` - в буфер обмена?

Comment: http://itnotesblog.ru/note.php?id=263 Ну и в общем про QClipboard погуглите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а если уж гуглить лень:

```py
if( c = QApplication.clipboard() ) != None:
    c.setText( text )
```

где `text` – то, что Вам нужно положить в буфер.

Условие использовано на случай, если `QApplication.clipboard()` вдруг вернёт `None`.

Подробнее [здесь](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard/) или по любой другой хорошей ссылке из результатов поиска Google по запросу *работа с буфером обмена PyQt*.

А ещё в Python есть свои средства для работы с буфером обмена:

```py
import win32clipboard

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

где `data` – Ваши данные для буфера.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGridLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QInputDialog,
                             QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QClipboard

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textEdit_1 = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit_1.insertPlainText("Используйте мышь для копирования текста в буфер обмена.\n"
                                        "Текст может быть скопирован из любого приложения.\n")
        self.btnChangeText = QPushButton("btnChangeText")
        self.btnChangeText.clicked.connect(self.changetext)   

        self.textEdit_2 = QTextEdit()
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnChangeText, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1)


        # Мы можем получить доступ к буферу, используя класс QClipboard. 
        # Затем мы можем вывести этот текст. 
        # Мы подключаем буфер обмена к методу, использующему строку:
        QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChanged)

    # Получить содержимое системного буфера обмена
    def clipboardChanged(self):
        # Затем мы захватываем содержимое, используя:
        text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
        self.textEdit_2.insertPlainText(text + '\n')

    def changetext(self):
        text, status = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Установка текста', 'Введите текст, например: Hello World')
        print(f"text={text}, status={status}")
        if text: 
            self.lineEdit.setText(text)   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    a_window.resize(700, 300)
    a_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]