# Скопировать текст из поля по кнопке в Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlineedit, qclipboard

Нужен код для копирования текста из поля `lineEdit_1` по кнопке `button_copy` для Python 3.8 с использованием Qt5

Хочу скопировать в буфер обмена.

Я писал так, но у меня почему-то не копирует:

```
def skopirovat(): 
    cb = QApplication.clipboard() 
    cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard) 
    cb.setText(self.ui.lineEdit_1.toPlainText(), mode=cb.Clipboard) 
    
self.ui.button_copy.clicked.connect(skopirovat)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ballow, покажите ваш код, который вы уже написали и лучше расскажите куда вы хотите скопировать текста из поля lineEdit_1.

Comment: просто хочу скопировать в буфер обмена.

Comment: примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017442/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-pyqt5/1017461#1017461

Comment: я писал так, но у меня почему-то не копирует.                                                                                   
def skopirovat ():
    cb = QApplication.clipboard()
    cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
    cb.setText(self.ui.lineEdit_1.toPlainText(), mode=cb.Clipboard)

    self.ui.button_copy.clicked.connect(skopirovat)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: если, что это приложение с интерфейсом.

Comment: ballow, если, что, то не забудьте пометить ответ как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
   
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        
        self.button_copy = QPushButton('button_copy')
        self.button_copy.clicked.connect(self.skopirovat)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_copy, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 1, 4, 1)
        
    def skopirovat(self): 
        cb = QApplication.clipboard() 
        cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard) 
        cb.setText(self.lineEdit.text(), mode=cb.Clipboard) 
        
        text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(f'{text}\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно так [link](https://prnt.sc/AncsN1S-KRQH)

Comment: @ballow кому нужно?

Comment: @ballow вы спросили как скопировать текст из поля по кнопке, я ответил вам. Что не так?

Comment: все работает, спасибо! чутка только нужно было поправить кнопки.